# How can I check that PowerPoint or point viewer is installed on the machine?

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

I need to play PowerPoint slides but first I want to check whether PowerPoint or viewer is installed on the machine or not. How can I do that using .NET?

Comment: Do you mean including open-office or other programs that can open powerpoints?

Comment: do you like to asp.net or c#.net give clear information

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether you are trying to tell whether you can view a presentation (*.ppt, *.pptx, etc) or whether you can access the PowerPoint object model.

To check whether there is an associated handler for ppt files, you can do the following:

```
// using Microsoft.Win32;
private bool CheckPowerPointAssociation() {
    var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".ppt", false);
    if (key != null) {
        key.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (CheckPowerPointAssociation()) {
    Process.Start(pathToPPT);
}
```

To check whether the PowerPoint COM object model is available, you can check the following registry key.

```
// using Microsoft.Win32;
private bool CheckPowerPointAutomation() {
    var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("PowerPoint.Application", false);
    if (key != null) {
        key.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (CheckPowerPointAutomation()) {
    var powerPointApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    ....
}
```

Note, however, that in both cases it will only give you a pretty good indication of the availability of PowerPoint. For example, an uninstallation may not have fully removed all traces. Also in my experience selling an Outlook addin for years I've seen certain antivirus programs that interfere with the COM object model in a screwup effort to protect against malicious scripts. So in any case, have robust error handling as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Things have changed with Office 2013. If the user has never installed a previous version of Office, then the registry entry is "PowerPoint.Application.15" for PowerPoint 2013. I am still looking for a good solution to this problem now that Microsoft changed the registry key name.

Comment: While I don't have a "clean" system to verify that, I'll just say that it seems highly unlikely. It's always been the case there there's a version-specific ProgID (ie PowerPoint.Application.15) and a non-version-specific ProgID (PowerPoint.Application) which both point to the same CLSID.

Comment: Perhaps. I was supporting a user of our product, and he shared his screen with me so I could examine his registry myself. Our test to see if PPT was installed was failing because there was no "PowerPoint.Application" key. This user didn't seem the type to have mangled his Office registry entries. I'd love to find out that I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MSPowerPoint\protocol\StdFileEditing\server

This key is the same for all installs of PowerPoint and points to the install dir for the executable to run PowerPoint. Great to use when detecting if this product is installed and good for figuring out which folder Office products are installed in, when the install is not using the defaults.

Comment: Things have changed with Office 2013. It seems that if the user has never installed a previous version of Office, then the registry entry is "ms-powerpoint" instead of "MSPowerPoint".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the right way to do this. But you can use this

```
try
{
    //It will throw a WIN32 Exception if there is no associated 
    //application available to open the file.
    Process p = Process.Start("C:\\Sample.pptx");
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Powerpoint or Powerpoint viewer not installed\n");
}
```

Comment: I think building your logic upon raising error is not the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking if the EXE file for PowerPoint or PowerPoint viewer exists or not by using "Exists Method" from system.io namespace?

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx).

Comment: Will it work? Because the User can install the application any where in his system.