# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I use Imports statement for PowerPoint automation in my VB.NET application:

```
Imports PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
```

and of course, I have to check if PowerPoint is installed in the user's machine or not. However, because of this reference the application does not start or load to give me the chance to check if PowerPoint is installed or not. Here is the code I use to check in Form Loading

```
Dim officeType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application")
If officeType Is Nothing Then
MessageBox.Show("PPT is not installed")
Else
MessageBox.Show("PPT is installed")
End If
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: [How can I check that PowerPoint or point viewer is installed on the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1991146/10216583)

Comment: The problem is not How to Check, the problem is adding "Imports PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" cause a problem in loading the application of PowerPoint is not installed. So, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Then don't use the Imports directives but just `Dim powerPointType =  Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application")`, then create the instance: `dim PowerPoint = Activator.CreateInstance(powerPointType)` if it exists (it may throw, so try/catch here).

Comment: **"Imports PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" cause a problem in loading the application** - this implies that your application is expecting the interop library to be located in the GAC.  In the solution window under the References node, right-click on "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" and select properties. Likely, both the "Copy Local" and "Embed Interop Types" properties are set to False.  While debugging, "Copy Local" should be set to true. For release, "Embed Interop Types" = True. Create the application instance as Jimi suggested to avoid version dependency.

Comment: Thank you @Jimi I removed Imports and replaced it by Dim powerPointType, it works now.

Comment: @TnTinMn , based on Jimi comment it works, but in VS 2019 Copy Local is read only and not able to change it to True, any way it works, thank you, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) and [TbTinMn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) comments I solved the problem. I replaced Imports statement by `Dim powerPointType` and recreated the application instance as follows: 
Under Public Class Form1, add

```
'// PowerPoint automation
Dim PowerPointType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application")
Dim PowerPoint = Activator.CreateInstance(PowerPointType)
Dim oApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
```

then you can complete your code with PPT application, for example, Export or Save as

```
'// open MS PowerPoint with hidden window
oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open(ppt_filename, , , Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse)
```

Comment: What about memory releasing and when?